# Отдача файла на скачивание

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Можно ли не используя серверную часть, а jQuery, не открывать изображение, а сразу отдать его на скачивание?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду скачивание по нажатию на ссылку?

Comment: Да, именно это меня интересует.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Без использования серверной части нужное вам действие можно реализовать, используя атрибут `download`:

```html
<a href="http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/new_tn2s/lamborghini-racing-car_tn2.jpg" download>Скачать изображение</a>
```

Подробнее про атрибут `download` читайте [тут](https://webref.ru/html/a/download).

Поддержку браузерами можно увидеть [тут](http://caniuse.com/#search=download).

---

Если нужно **решение** именно **на js/jQuery**, можно копнуть в сторону [DownloadJS](https://github.com/PixelsCommander/Download-File-JS) и ему подобных готовых решений.

Пример работы:

```js
window.downloadFile = function(sUrl) {

  //iOS devices do not support downloading. We have to inform user about this.
  if (/(iP)/g.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    alert('Your device does not support files downloading. Please try again in desktop browser.');
    return false;
  }

  //If in Chrome or Safari - download via virtual link click
  if (window.downloadFile.isChrome || window.downloadFile.isSafari) {
    //Creating new link node.
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = sUrl;

    if (link.download !== undefined) {
      //Set HTML5 download attribute. This will prevent file from opening if supported.
      var fileName = sUrl.substring(sUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, sUrl.length);
      link.download = fileName;
    }

    //Dispatching click event.
    if (document.createEvent) {
      var e = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
      e.initEvent('click', true, true);
      link.dispatchEvent(e);
      return true;
    }
  }

  // Force file download (whether supported by server).
  if (sUrl.indexOf('?') === -1) {
    sUrl += '?download';
  }

  window.open(sUrl, '_self');
  return true;
}

window.downloadFile.isChrome = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('chrome') > -1;
window.downloadFile.isSafari = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') > -1;
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="downloadFile('https://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/52627/52627,1331024875,4/stock-vector-vector-illustration-of-soft-colored-abstract-background-96845341.jpg');">Скачать картинку</a>
```

**Еще несколько вариантов:**

- [File downloading using client-side JavaScript](https://github.com/rndme/download)
- [jQuery File Download](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload)
- [How to force download a file with JavaScript](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OVjOgE)
- [Download Files with JavaScript](https://www.tutsandtips.com/javascript/how-to-download-a-file-with-javascript/)